# Flutter & Firestore: The error will occur when data in the field type timestamp has a value before 1/1/1970 at 7 AM

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

It can set timestamp value before 1/1/1970 at 7 AM in firestore like this:
[image]

But when I fetch this data in my flutter project the error will alert with this:

```
Error: Invalid argument(s): Timestamp nanoseconds out of range: -233000000
```

How to solve this?
I just try to check the range of timestamp ( '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC).

It works successfully when I set the timestamp field after `2038-01-19 03:14:07` (I found the limit of year is 10,000).

Should I record DateTime with the timestamp type or I should save it in the String type?
What is the field type that most people used for DateTime in firestore?

Comment: what is the result if you remove UTC+7 this part ?

Comment: Hi @TasnuvaTavasumoshin, how I remove this?  
In the firestore, I only can select `Date` and `Time` with DateTime input. I don't see any options to remove `UTC+7` in firestore.
In the flutter, The error will occur after I using `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').get().then(value){}`. This error happened before I do anything with this result (the result from the firestore is the `value` parameter that contains many documents and in some documents have a field that type is a timestamp that has a value that makes an error ).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just save the dates as strings and use the DateTime.parse() method in flutter or something similar in your backend code when needing to convert it back. An exception to this would be if you need to perform queries on your Firestore docs based on these dates.

Comment: Sorry I don't have an easy solution to still using DateTime for you

Comment: It's ok. This is a good alternative when this issue is a bug.